# IOS6 How can I listen to Interface orientation. Not device orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, ios6

I need to know when orientation switch from portrait to landscape and vise versa. 
If I choose to listen to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` I get face up, face down etc, but I need to run code only when there is a interface rotation.

I could do as http://the.ichibod.com/kiji/how-to-handle-device-rotation-for-uiviews-in-ios/

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

 //Obtaining the current device orientation
  UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

 //Ignoring specific orientations
  if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown     || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown || currentOrientation == orientation) {
   return;
  }

  [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(relayoutLayers) object:nil];
  //Responding only to changes in landscape or portrait
  currentOrientation = orientation;
}
```

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems orientating my views when using device orientation. It has up, down, left and right but also unknown and another which I yet to figure it out what it means (int 5 on the enum, 0 being Unknown). Anyways, what I ended up resorting to was to detect the status bar orientation. That remains more consistency for what the user is seeing.

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really nice! But I still need to save the last orientation so I can compare and make sure that it´s a rotate from portrait to landscape and not from face up to landscape?

Comment: Just store a previous orientation state as a class var, so when your view appears, save the orientation where it is at to begin with. Then implement it on deviceorientationdidchange.

Comment: So Apple deprecated willrotatetointerfaceorientation and they haven´t got any good alternative. Oh lord!